# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (638,) (0,) (638,)

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and shapes concept. What does the below error say?

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (638,) (0,) (638,)

I have two arrays x and y for 10 unique ID's.

Out of 10 ID's 7 are good and 3 throws error.

And am performing the below statement for each ID

```
x *= y
```

Comment: Are these numpy arrays? can you print the x and y that give you the error? It looks like one of your arrays has an empty array within it

Comment: Printing x.shape and y.shape would also be useful for seeing if that is the case

Comment: Got the issue, i didnt see that x is an array and y was a list. i forgot to convert y to array and thus resulted. Thank you @KeithJohnson